# Tensor product of a field with itself.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

I am proving the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are two central $k$-algebras where $k$ is a field (so then $Z(A) = Z(B) = k$), then $A \otimes B$ is also central. I made almost everything except this: I came up with the fact that $Z(A \otimes B) = k \otimes k$. But is it really true that $k \otimes k = k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\otimes=\otimes_k$. Then $\varphi: k\otimes k\rightarrow k$ with $1\otimes 1\mapsto 1\cdot 1=1$ is the inverse of  $\rho: k\rightarrow k\otimes k$, $1\mapsto 1\otimes 1$.

Comment: And to which element the $\varphi$ sends, say pure tensor $a \otimes b$?

Comment: $a\otimes b=ab\otimes 1$. Define $\varphi(c\otimes 1):=c\cdot 1$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome; as $a\otimes b=1\otimes ab$, then you can introduce $\varphi(1\otimes c):=1\cdot c$ as well, leading to the same result as before. The unit $1$ commutes with all elements in $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ground field is an up-to-isomorphism unit, that is $k\otimes k \cong k$. The proof is quite straightforward no matter which definition of the tensor product you use.

Comment: No matter which definition we use?  How about the definition $k \otimes k = k \otimes_{\ell} k$ where $\ell$ is a proper subfield of $k$ (assuming $k$ is not ${\mathbf Q}$ or ${\mathbf F}_p$)?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of thinking of this is in terms of dimension. A field can be viewed as a one dimensional vector space over the same field. Now the dimension of the tensor product of such a vector space with itself is the product of dimensions, $1\times 1=1$ and itself a vector space over that field which would be isomorphic with the field being a one dimensional vector space.