# How is the exterior product of multilinear forms defined with exterior algebra

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, exterior-algebra

Similar topic but different concern with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857586/what-is-the-wedge-product-of-multilinear-forms)

In the Exterior_algebra of Wikipedia, there is:

> Under this identification, the exterior product takes a concrete form: it produces a new anti-symmetric map from two given ones. Suppose $ω$ : $V_k \to K$ and $η$ : $V_m \to K$ are two anti-symmetric forms. As in the case of tensor products of multilinear maps, the number of variables of their exterior product is the sum of the numbers of their variables. It is defined as follows:
> $$ω\wedge η=\frac{(k+m)!}{k!m!}Alt(ω\otimes η) $$

Here are confusions about the definition:

(1) Both $ω$ and $η$ are alternating multilinear forms, their tensor product $ω\otimes η$ should be a multilinear map whose image space is $K\otimes K$ instead of $K$, then the result of the above formular should also be such multilinear map which is not multilinear form anymore (guess not)?

If no, then I guess $ω$ and $η$ in the above formular are any representative tensor in $T^k(V^*)$ for their corresponding elements in $\Lambda^k(V^*)$? Since this is "compatible" with the common definition of the map $Alt$ which map tensor to tensor.

(2) How is the coefficient $\frac{(k+m)!}{k!m!}$ produced? The note in the article says this is only a convention. Also note that the $Alt$ in the article already includes the $\frac{1}{k!}$ factor, then there is double copy of the $\frac{1}{k!}$ factor. Also there is no such factor in $Alt$ in Dummit's book.

Comment: $K\otimes K$ is canonically isomorphic to $K$ when $K$ is the ground field, so you can just identify them, see [Tensor product of a field with itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/589652/152568). The factor is the result of a convention where you normalize the alternation of a $k$-form by the total number of permutations, $k!$ Many authors do not normalize, and hence do not need this factor.

Comment: @Conifold (1) But the $Alt$ in the article already contains the k! factor which means there is two copies of k! factor - is that a bug in the article? (2) I think there should not be convention (i.e. I think this is a bug too), it has to have the right factor to make the result a alternating one.

Comment: It's because it has k! factor in the permutational definition that you need another factor when defining the wedge. You are free to scale the alternation as you wish, you just have to make sure that the same convention is followed in all formulas.